# An MVC view model collection is being populated and seen in Fiddler, but is null when reaches the controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I have 3 nested models, `LevelViewModel`, `LevelContentViewModel`, and `LevelContentDomainViewModel`. The Model `LevelContent` has multiple properties, to include:

```
public List<LevelContentDomainViewModel> Domains { get; set; }
```

The `LevelContentDomainViewModel` has properties

```
public int DomainId { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Domain Name")]
public string DomainName { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Available")]
public bool Included { get; set; }
```

View 1 takes a `LevelView` model, and a list of `LevelContent` items. The edit button on each item goes to a partial view `EditLevelContent.cshtml`, which is rendered within View 1

```
EditLevelContent.cshtml
```

This has a checkbox for each item in Domains list

```
    using (Html.BeginForm("EditLevelContent", "Level", FormMethod.Post  )) 
...
   @for (int d = 0; d < Model.Domains.Count; d++)
     {
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Domains[d].DomainId)
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Domains[d].DomainName, Model.Domains[d].DomainName)
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Domains[d].Included,Model.Domains[d].Included)
      }
```

the model is posted back and received by the controller action,

```
public ActionResult EditLevelContent([Bind(Include = "Id,SelectedContentId,SortOrder,SelectedLevelId")] LevelContentViewModel levelContentModel)
```

`levelContentModel` is populated, but it's property Domains is always null.

In **Fiddler** I can see that there are values being posted for `Domains[0].DomainName` and `Domains[0].Included` right through to 8.  If I include the Domains property as a `hidden` field, it makes no difference.

Thanks!

Comment: First remove your `[Bind]` attribute. It excludes `Domains` from binding, and a `[Bind` attribute is never needed when using view models anyway. As a side note its just `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Domains[d].DomainName)` and `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Domains[d].Included)` - the 2nd parameters are pointless

Comment: Brilliant.  Removing the [Bind] worked. Thanks